# Why this code is not working for specific type of data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, sum

```
def find_even_index(arr):
    for a in arr:
        b = arr.index(a)
        if sum(arr[b+1:]) == sum(arr[:b]):
            return b
    return -1

find_even_index([20,10,30,10,10,15,35])
>>> -1
```

My code works for all type of data except when it encounters a same digit before or after the number. The index does not change for other 10. Why?

Comment: `arr.index(a)` returns the first index matching `a`. It won't do what you expect if there are duplicates.

Comment: Why are you looping over the elements? Just loop over the indexes: `for b in range(len(arr)):`

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, you are the best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just writing out the solution that @Barmar is suggesting in his comments (+1):

```
def find_even_index(array):
    for index in range(len(array)):
        if sum(array[:index]) == sum(array[index + 1:]):
            return index

    return -1

print(find_even_index([20, 10, 30, 10, 10, 15, 35]))
```

Alternatively, if we wanted to avoid so many calls to `sum()`, and make good use of `enumerate()`, we could try:

```
def find_even_index(array):
    total = sum(array)

    partial_sum = 0

    for index, number in enumerate(array):
        if total - partial_sum == number:
            return index

        partial_sum += number * 2

    return -1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `list.index()` function will only return the index of the specified object closest to the start of the list. You can instead use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate through the list alongside each object's index:

```
def find_even_index(arr):
    for i, a in enumerate(arr): # For index, number in arr
        b = i
        if sum(arr[b+1:]) == sum(arr[:b]):
            return b
    return -1

print(find_even_index([20,10,30,10,10,15,35]))
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: Why use `enumerate()` if you don't use `a`?

Comment: @Barmar Well, I often see this happen.